# Numbered anchors in doxygen

Tags: anchor, doxygen

I have quite a lot of anchors to picture in doxygen, e.g.

```
\anchor pic_foo
\image html foo.gif "My Caption"
\anchor pic_bar
\image html bar.gif "My Caption"
```

Everytime when I use `\ref` to link one of those, I have to make up
some nice description so the raw name of the anchor doesn't appear in
output.

Is it possible to have something like numbered anchors in doxygen
where the link text will be the number of that anchor? Ideally
something like:

```
\anchor pic_foo
\image html foo.gif "My Caption"
\anchor pic_bar
\image html bar.gif "My Caption"

As Figure \ref pic_foo shows... Figure \ref pic_bar is...
```

should ideally translate to:

```
As Figure 1 shows... Figure 2 is...
```

where the number is the link. I would be happy with every kind of counting scheme (documentation global or page local).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that automatic number of figures, either within a page or across the whole documentation, is possible with doxygen (I would be happy to be corrected here). However, an easy solution to your question is the replace your anchor text with spelt out numbers, i.e. "one", "two", "three"... etc. Alternatively, if you have lots of figures you could use Roman numerals. Plain numbers don't seem to work as anchor links.

Your example will then become, with additional text in the figure captions,

```
\anchor one
\image html foo.gif "Figure one: My Caption"
\anchor two
\image html bar.gif "Figure two: My Caption"

As Figure \ref one shows... Figure \ref two is...
```

resulting in

```
Here Figure one shows... Figure two is...
```

with `one` and `two` hyperlinks to your figures.

You can then define a alias in your configuration file, say `\fref`, defined to be `Figure \ref` which will automatically preceed the hyperlinked numbers with the text "Figure".

Is this solution acceptable? The only other alternative I can think of involves post processing the doxygen output, but the above solution is by far the simplest.

**Update**

The following Python code will transform anchor references to an incrementing counter:

```
# Test documentation.
s = r"""
\anchor pic_foo
\image html foo.gif "My Caption"
\anchor pic_bar
\image html bar.gif "My Caption"

As Figure \ref pic_foo shows... Figure \ref pic_bar is...
"""

# Split string into a list of lines.
s = s.split('\n')

# Dictionaries for mapping anchor names to an incrementing counter.
d = {}

numbers = {1: 'one',
    2 : 'two',
    3 : 'three'}

counter = 1

# Find all anchor links and map to the next counter value.
for line in s:
    if r'\anchor' in line:
        d[line.split(r'\anchor ')[1]] = numbers[counter]
        counter += 1

# Reform original string.
s = '\n'.join(s)

# Replace anchor links with appropriate counter value.
for key, value in d.items():
    s = s.replace(key, value)

print s
```

Running this script results in the output

```
\anchor one
\image html foo.gif "My Caption"
\anchor two
\image html bar.gif "My Caption"

As Figure \ref one shows... Figure \ref two is...
```

It is trivial to modify the above script to read from standard input and write to standard out, so this can easily be used in conjunction with the `INPUT_FILTER` configuration file option.

One thing to note is that the dictionary `numbers` has to be extended to allow for more than three figures to be included. This is again trivial, but probably not easily scalable. Solutions for mapping from arbitrary numbers to the appropriate word(s) are available (see other questions on this site) so I haven't bothered to implement this here.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but this is out of the question. Imagine adding a new image between the two. Sure, I always have my Emacs function increment-number-word and can make that as painless as possible. I still don't think any of my contributors would agree.

Comment: This is of course not ideal, but I think it is the simplest solution you will find since [doxygen doesn't seem to have any commands](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html) or [autolink options](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/autolink.html) for implementing an incrementing counter. You could instead write a script or XLST for modifying the XML generated by doxygen. However, I would question whether it is worth it just to avoid renaming some figure labels every so often (presumably once your documentation is nearly complete the figures are not likely to change much).

Comment: I'd rather go for a shell script that can be used as an INPUT_FILTER to achieve that effect. Think of the bounty while you implement it! ;)

Comment: Ha! I wil do. I have been trying to implement a solution using preprocessors (using, say, [__COUNTER__](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros) but unfortunately macros do not get expanded in comments. I'll have a think about a script and possibly post another answer if I come up with anything.

Comment: @pmr I have added a Python script which does what you are after. It is not particularly robust, but it does what you ask for in the question. The only difference is you can't have numbers as reference links, so I have used `one`, `two` etc instead of 1, 2,...

Comment: Very nice. I stumbled over another possible solution when I implemented footnotes. You can use JQuery! After I came to that realization I just reached a completely new level of thinking about doxygen documentation.

Comment: That sounds very interesting. Can you share how you implemented footnotes, maybe as another answer or in chat? I would love to see that.

Comment: @pmr Please share how you implemented footnotes!

Comment: @ScottDeerwester I use and include it in the generated documentation. http://www.planetholt.com/articles/jQuery-Footnotes and add my own `ALIASES += "myFootnote{1}=<span class=\"footnote\">\1</span>"`. I add a function through `$(document).ready` that does `$("#doc-content").append('<ol id="autoFootnotes0" class="footnotesList"></ol>'); $("body").footnotes();` and there you go.

Comment: @pmr Would you care to contribute this as an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290453/how-do-i-add-a-footnote-in-doxygen ?