# Doxygen auto number formulas

Tags: css, latex, doxygen, formula

I would like to enter several formulas into my Doxygen documentation.  Is there any way to create a label of some type that automatically numbers each formula?  Ideally, the automatic numbering will work both in HTML generated output and within Latex generated output from Doxygen.  I am looking for something similar to the Caption feature in MS Word.

Example:

```
You can see the results of my example in Equation 1.1 below.

{Some Formula}

                                               Equation 1.1

{Some other formula}

                                               Equation 1.2
```

In the example above, the number after "Equation" gets automatically generated.  And then I can reference it in the text.

The \anchor feature in Doxygen would allow me to link to the locations.  But I don't think that it would generate the auto-numbering correctly.

The option I thought of was to modify my CSS that I use for Doxygen.  Currently I already modified it to automatically number my headings.  And Latex automatically numbers headings 1-4 already.  I could change my CSS to format Heading 4 so that it looks like a right-justified equation label.  But I don't know how I can get Latex to use the same formatting.

Any helpful suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799435/numbered-anchors-in-doxygen?rq=1  There's some useful info on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I learned, this can not be done in Doxygen.  I am now considering two authoring systems to do this:

1. Doxygen to document the code.
2. Open Office / Libre Office to document user manuals, which is where the bulk of the equations are.

Both authoring apps will write HTML output.  And then I will combine the output with Qt Help Project system.