# How do I add a footnote in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I'd like to insert a numbered (or other, I'm not picky) footnote in my doxygen output. The [list of special commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) doesn't include anything that I could identify as enabling this. I was hoping for something like:

```
This is my text.\footnote{This is my footnote}
```

which would produce

> This is my text.<sup>1</sup>

and then

> 1: This is my footnote

at the bottom of the page. Is there a way to accomplish this or something functionally equivalent?

Comment: Does something in [this](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/customize.html) page help (have a look at the footer section).

Comment: @roelofs Not that I was able to see. The footer section lets you add a footer that's common to all pages, so it wouldn't help you add a footnote entry to just one page, unless I'm misunderstanding what it says.

Comment: I found another link relating to numbered anchors.  The idea seems roughly the same - maybe it'll be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799435/numbered-anchors-in-doxygen

Comment: @roelofs There's a very intriguing comment there about implementing footnotes, but without a description of how. I've added a comment, hoping to motivate the author to share what he did. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Yeah, saw that too - I hope you find something!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your own \footnote command via the ALIASES option in doxygen's configuration file like this:

```
ALIASES = footnote{1}="\latexonly\footnote\{\1\}\endlatexonly\htmlonly<sup title=\"\1\">*</sup>\endhtmlonly"
```

This will produce a real footnote in the LaTeX output and a <sup>*</sup> with a tooltip in the HTML output.

Answer (score 9):

Good question! *What follows is a bit of a hack but might serve your needs.*

Start from the *footnote* text at the bottom of your page and use an `\anchor` to mark it.

`\anchor wibble 1. Wibble is an unusual shade of pink.`

You can then link to the footnote using a `\ref`

`Amongst the odder plants of the upper Amazon basin is the wibble rose (\ref wibble "1").  Water buffalo are particularly fond of wibble roses.`

should produce

> Amongst the odder plants of the upper Amazon basin is the wibble rose
>   (**1**).  Water buffalo are particularly fond of wibble roses.
>
> 1. Wibble is an unusual shade of pink.

Yes, you are having to do rather too much manually, but at least this gives some form of hyperlinked footnote.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose that I could also do something like (\ref wibble "<sup>1</sup>") if I wanted to get fancy... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: (I'll wait a bit to see if anybody else manages to come up with a more direct method, before marking this as the definitive answer.)

Comment: +1 Thank you. Really nice answer. I prefer it to the alias responses, because this method conserves more or less the same structure between the doxygen comment and the rendered html code (doxygen comments should imho be still easy to read in the source code).

Comment: (\ref wibble "<sup>1</sup>") not worked. use <sup>(\ref wibble "1")</sup> instead

Answer (score 5):

To produce footnotes in HTML I currently use a mixture of ALIASES commands and some custom JS.

The command looks like this:

```
ALIASES += "myFootnote{1}=<span class=\"footnote\">\1</span>"
```

You might want to improve this alias to also cover footnotes in LaTeX through a `\latexonly` and `\htmlonly`.

In the `header.html` for my project I add the script found here. http://www.planetholt.com/articles/jQuery-Footnotes
To initialize the footnotes I also add the following code inside a script tag to `header.html`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#doc-content").append('<ol id="autoFootnotes0" class="footnotesList"></ol>');
    $("body").footnotes();
});
```